# Visiting multiple US and CA cities - ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I'm traveling to the US for tourism, first to the East Coast, after that to Canada for a weekend, and then back to the US, West Coast. I'm using the ESTA Visa Waiver Program, and they require local contact information.

Do I need to refill the ESTA when traveling back to the US from Canada or is the "old ESTA" valid for this also?

Comment: Note that if you are flying to the US you will provide a contact address every time you enter, both via the airline APIS and on the customs form if you fill it out. Since you are entering twice on this trip you can give them the east coast address for the first entry and the west coast address for the second. Since they are getting the addresses this way they really don't need you to provide the same addresses via an additional method (like the ESTA).

Comment: @Dennis the customs form asks for the *traveler's* address in the US, not a contact address. If you will be moving around, this is normally the place where you will spend the first night after your arrival. For example, if you stay in a hotel while you visit someone, the address you should use on the customs form is the hotel address.

Answer (score 2):

Chose the first because if not allowed entry an your first attempt (East Coast) the second attempt (West Coast) is unlikely to be relevant. Though to be fair I think here is considerable doubt about why this detail is required - and therefore what the "right" answer should be.

See also [Do I need to change my ESTA address when visiting the US again?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45832/do-i-need-to-change-my-esta-address-when-visiting-the-us-again)

and [Do I need to provide a US contact when applying for an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67823/do-i-need-to-provide-a-us-contact-when-applying-for-an-esta)

You only need one ESTA for both visits since its function is to qualify you for the Visa Waiver Program and it usually does so for [two years at a time](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/~/esta---length-of-approval) (subject to some changes in circumstances - essentially to the Yes/No answers at the end of the ESTA application).

From [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDg1NjI0MDE1L3NpZC92WU5RalE5bg%3D%3D):

> If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes. The associated fee of $14 will be charged for each new application.